# Shadows are green, light or intense

Tags: shadows

I am following BlenderGuru's tutorial on Blender, the donut, and everything has been fine except for this. First, I noticed in medium-light renders a greenish hue or tone. I had the donut laying on a metallic blue table so I thought it was a reflection thing going on. Later I changed the table to a lighter cream color, and it was still present. And after I applied displacement the green in the shadows fully reveals.  I can not remember if shadows were like that in the very beginning of modeling or if it is something I did along the way but I have solidly followed the tutorial, so doubt it. I am now thinking it is either software, or a hardware issue going on. Also thought it could be the display, I use an LG 4KHDR tv as a monitor, but nothing happened after turning HDR off and tweaking other stuff.

Thank you for your help! Pics attached

[image][image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It looks like you've enabled Subsurface Scattering with a higher green radius?

Comment: The lower picture looks almost like it's part of the material... have you changed the material on it? How is your scene lit? Have you accidentally turned on subsurface scattering or something? The file would be really helpful.